# Re-writing if-statements: One of these statements ended up with one too many pair of braces

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to write a method to ensure that all the if-statements in my tree are followed by braced code blocks. Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
                                                class Program
                                                {
                                                    static void main()
                                                    {
                                                        if(true)
                                                            Console.WriteLine(""It was true!"");
                                                        if(false)
                                                            Console.WriteLine(""It was false!"");
                                                    }
                                                }");

        var root = tree.GetRoot();
        var rewriter = new MyRewriter();

        var newRoot = rewriter.Visit(root);
        var ifStatements = newRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<IfStatementSyntax>();

        foreach (var ifStatement in ifStatements)
        {
            SyntaxNode newIfStatement = rewriter.VisitIfStatement(ifStatement);
            newRoot = newRoot.ReplaceNode(ifStatement, newIfStatement);
        }

        var result = newRoot;

        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class MyRewriter: CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxNode VisitIfStatement(IfStatementSyntax node)
    {
        var body = node.Statement;
        var block = SyntaxFactory.Block(body);
        var newIfStatement = node.WithStatement(block);

        return newIfStatement;
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

> class Program
>                                                       {
>                                                           static void main()
>                                                           {
>                                                               if(true) {{
>   Console.WriteL ine("It was true!"); }}
>   if(false) {
>   Console.WriteLi ne("It was false!"); }
>   }
>                                                       }

As you can see, the code block following the first if-statement is braced twice (*not* as intended), whereas the code block following the second if-statement is braced only once (as intended).

I am sure that I hold some erroneous assumptions about how Roslyn works, so will someone kindly advise me on what went wrong? What changes should I make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing two things: either you use a `SyntaxRewriter` or you do it "manually". Right now you're doing both: first you call the rewriter and afterwards you loop through all its nodes and call the rewriter again on each `IfStatementSyntax`.

- Fixing all `if` statements: `var newRoot = rewriter.Visit(root);`
- Manually replacing all `if` statements:

```
var ifStatements = newRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<IfStatementSyntax>();

foreach (var ifStatement in ifStatements)
{
    SyntaxNode newIfStatement = rewriter.VisitIfStatement(ifStatement);
    newRoot = newRoot.ReplaceNode(ifStatement, newIfStatement);
}
```

You can omit the looping altogether: this is specifically the task of a `SyntaxRewriter`.

> Why did only the first statement get two braces?

Multiple modifications to a tree should be done through a `DocumentEditor` for example. After your first replacement, the second `IfStatementSyntax` inside your `ifStatements` collection was out of sync with the newly created syntax tree that you received as a result from your first replacement. Because it was out of sync, the location of the original `ifStatementSyntax` was now at a different location in the newly created tree (a bracket had been added --> depending on the formatting applied, this moves all characters at least one position).
Result: first replacement succeeds, second replacement fails (silently).

---

Further remark: apply formatting by adding the `Formatter` annotation to the added nodes and calling `Formatter.Format` afterwards like this:

```
var newRoot = rewriter.Visit(root).WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation);
var result = Formatter.Format(newRoot, Formatter.Annotation, new AdhocWorkspace());
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! Can you motivate why you suggested that I should apply formatting?

Comment: Because if you print it without that annotation, it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/0cvpZaR.png That's not very pretty ;-) With the annotation you get this: http://i.imgur.com/uXZAQ8k.png